# How to re-use the header, footer template on content template loop

Tags: jquery, templates, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am not so familiar with `underscore` template. I am trying to print a page with 3 content element with 3 data of each shown.

Each one of the `content` need to have a header and continue element with them. the last one should have the footer template instead of continue.

I don't have any idea how to achieve this at all... any one help me please?

here is my try:

```
<script type="text/template" id="header">
    <div id="header">
        <h6>this is Header</h6>
        <span><% students.name[0] %></span>
   </div>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="content">
    <div id="content">
    <h6>Content</h6>
    <% _.each(students, function (item, index) { %>
        <% if(index % 3 == 0 ) { %>
           <% return $('#header').html() %>
        <% } %>
        <li><%= item.name %></li>
    <% }) %>
            </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="continue">
     <span>Continue....</span>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="footer">
    <div id="footer>
    <span>End of Document</span>
</div>
</script>
```

No luck. any one please help me?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r7bu6o3n/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your primary question is how to recursively evaluate templates. This works fine, you just want to be careful to use `<%= %>` rather than `<% %>` and pass them whatever argument they should have access to when called by the parent template.

```
// http://jsfiddle.net/uwmbznxb/1/
<script type="text/template" id="header">
<div id="header">
    <h6>this is Header</h6>
    <span><%= name[0] %></span>
</div>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="content">
   <div id="content">
   <h6>Content</h6>
   <% _.each(students, function (item, index) { %>
        <% if(index % 3 == 0 ) { %>
            <% if (index) { %>
                   <%= _.template($('#continue').html())(item) %>
            <% } %>
           <%= _.template($('#header').html())(item) %>
        <% } %>
        <li><%= item.name %></li>
    <% }) %>
        <%= _.template($('#footer').html())({}) %>
            </div>
 </script>
 // other templates ..
```

Comment: I accept. But the footer is not printing there.. here is the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/r7bu6o3n/2/ - can you please make change?

Comment: @3gwebtrain you have a typo closing #footer's id, I already repaired it in http://jsfiddle.net/uwmbznxb/1/ in my answer

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I tried the same with my template, but the "all are done" from the footer not printing as a last statement. instead prints before the table. here is the live: http://jsfiddle.net/ffk5raqL/ - if you don't mine, can  you help me to solve this..? thanks in advance. please correct me wherever i do wrongs.

Comment: @3gwebtrain you just left a dangling table. An open table pulls later elements in and renders them above normal table elements. http://jsfiddle.net/ffk5raqL/1/

Comment: Yes. you are correct. very thanks to you. saved a lot time for me!

Comment: I got the issue again, when my `limit` variable got the full length as `11`, i got printed both `continue` and `All are done`.  demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ffk5raqL/2/ - to avoid this I added a extra condition : http://jsfiddle.net/ffk5raqL/3/ - this is not working again. I understand that the way i am doing the condition is wrong. can you please correct me please?